# Close Keyboard when it's already visible

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, uikeyboard, uitextviewdelegate

I have a problem to close keyboard when I have more than 1 UITextField.

I have 2 TextField : `TextField1` and `TextField2` and I give each of them tag `1` and `2`

I want to make if tag equal to 2 then it's hide the keyboard and if I touch textfield with tag equal to 1 the keyboard visible again, that's work with my code but when I turn it back the code not do like what I want, I touch `TextField1` first then `TextField2` the keyboard still visible and not hiding

My code is like this

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) {
        if (textField.tag == 2) {
            self.view.endEditing(false)
            textField.resignFirstResponder()
        } else {
            self.view.endEditing(true)
        }
    }
```

I also try to use Events like `Editing Did Begin` and `Editing Changed` but can't do like what I want

Please help me how to make keyboard hide when it's is already visible

Comment: why are you resigning first responder or ending editing within a did begin editing delegate method? Won't that make it impossible to ever enter text?

Comment: @jrturton I want when I touch my TextField2 it's still have blinking cursor but not showing the Keyboard

Comment: Why is that? Is there some other method the user has for getting text into the text field?

Comment: refer @simplebob answer. That is the solution of your problem. self.view.endEditing(false) is not going to dismiss the keyboard ever.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) {
        if (textField.tag == 2) {
            self.view.endEditing(true)
        } else {
            textField.becomeFirstResponder()
        }
}
```

`self.view.endEditing(true)` will not show the keyboard, it actually will try to hide it forcing the first responder to resign.

Answer (score 0):

Try with below code.

```
-(BOOL) textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
     if(textField.tag == 2)
     {
          [[self.view viewWithTag:1] resignFirstResponder];
          return false;
     }
     else
     {
          return true;
     }
}
```

Comment: I made a typo when I write my code, the code is already compare tag with 2

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it like using below textfield delegate method,

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool
{
    if (textField == self.TextField1) {
        self.TextField2.becomeFirstResponder()
    }
    else {
        textField.resignFirstResponder()
        self.view.endEditing(true)
    }
    return true
}
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you didn't set UITextFieldDelgate on this class, So In the viewDidLoad()

```
  override func viewDidLoad() { 
         TextField1.delegate = self
         TextField2.delegate = self
    }
```

Then add **textFieldDidBeginEditing** like this :-

```
   func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) {
    if (textField.tag == 2) {
        self.view.endEditing(true)
    } else {
        textField.becomeFirstResponder()
    }
```

}